# jenkins git plugin cloning every time

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I created one job for polling the Git Source code.

First time it should clone the repository, and after that if repository exist then it should only `pull` it.

See the following setting for job.

[image]

**Problem:** every time when i run this job it always clone's it rather then polling it.

I'm Checking on **Fast remote polling**, It says that repository should have only one branch. So for that i'm specifying the branch name.

What i'm missing here..?

Comment: Hm I think this is the default behaviour. Note 'polling' =/= 'pulling' :-)

Comment: @Dratir Default behavior means? will it always clone. Let assume My git Repo size it 10GB or more and i want to run my job every in 30 mins then it will take more then hr to clone. I don't know if its a Default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure in slave git has latest version:
See below for more details:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please? @sumit singh

Comment: is there anything else also require other than whatever show in the picture?
ex: selecting "Fast remote polling"

Answer (score 1):

There was a [similar bug for Mercurial](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16138) which pointed out to a credential issue.
So double-check the way your credentials are passed (either through the url or stored in a file, like a `.netrc` for hhtps)

The point is: fast polling should fetch/pull, not clone. See [`hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM#compareRemoteRevisionWithImpl()`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/18e799814060256cabc7b607c919f356c184352f/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java#L716-L726).

```java
            if (git.hasGitRepo()) {
                // Repo is there - do a fetch
                listener.getLogger().println("Fetching changes from the remote Git repositories");

                // Fetch updates
                for (RemoteConfig remoteRepository : paramRepos) {
                    fetchFrom(git, listener, remoteRepository);
                }

                listener.getLogger().println("Polling for changes in");
```

Comment: Note: changes are in the work for "force polling using workspace": https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/181. That will have an influence on the "fast polling" feature.